# Generate a random string every time

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to generate a different string each time it sends the message. 
This works but the string doesn't change.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

function randomValueHex (len) {
return crypto.randomBytes(Math.ceil(len/2))
    .toString('hex')
    .slice(0,len).toUpperCase(); 
}

var string = randomValueHex(4)+"-"+randomValueHex(4)+"-"+randomValueHex(4);

bot.on('message', function(user, userID, channelID, message, event) {
if (message === "!test") {
  var interval = setInterval (function (){
    bot.sendMessage({
      to: channelID,
      message: string
    });
  }, 1000);
}
});
```

Comment: This is for Node.js. So please use `const` instead of `var`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move the `string` variable **into the function**. That way it will be different each time the function runs.

```
bot.on('message', function(user, userID, channelID, message, event) {
if (message === "!test") {
  const interval = setInterval (function (){
    const string = randomValueHex(4)+"-"+randomValueHex(4)+"-"+randomValueHex(4);
    bot.sendMessage({
      to: channelID,
      message: string
    });
  }, 1000);
}
});
```